# The property or field 'Exists' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed

Tags: csom

I have the following CSOM code to check if a folder exists:-

```
 private static void NewTryToAttachFiles(ClientContext ctx, Web web, List fromList, ListItem fromItem, List toList, ListItem toItem)
    {

     string src = string.Format("{0}/lists/{1}/Attachments/{2}", web.Url, "Lease Agreements", fromItem.Id);      
     if (web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(src).Exists)//this will raise the error

     //code goes here
     }
 
 context.Load(context.Web);
 context.ExecuteQuery();
 NewTryToAttachFiles(context,context.Web, oList2,item,oList,listItem2);
```

but i am getting this error:-

```
The property or field 'Exists' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested
```

so how i can load the `Exists` property?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it gets a Folder without actually loading the values for the folders properties.

Load the (needed) folder properties first before using them.

```
var folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(src)
context.Load(folder,  f=>f.Exists);
context.ExecuteQuery();

if (folder.Exists)
     //code goes here
}
```